# what is wrong with my jQuery POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to authenticate with a remote service through jQuery.  First, I verify that I can do this outside of the browser:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: appliction/json" -d '{"username":"...","password":"..."}' http://example.com/auth
```

This successfully returns a token.

Now I try it with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/auth",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "json",
    data: {username:"...",password:"..."},
    error: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data))},
    success: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data))}
});
```

I get a server error (500).  Clearly I am doing something wrong.  This is my first time trying to do a POST in jQuery, so I don't know how to identify what the problem is.  What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I can successfully do a GET request through jQuery, if I already have a token:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/stuff?token=f42652adcbfe3ed9d59fae62b5267b8d",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data))},
    success: function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data))}
});
```

Comment: why do you not use $.post function ? is much much easier and it uses AJAX as well :)

Comment: I really don't think that the server error (500) is related to your ajax request, it's probabily a server misconfiguration.

Comment: @Zsigoveny: It's functionally equivalent to this.

Comment: `data: {username:"...",password:"..."},` isn't json. If your server is expecting json, that's why it's failing.

Comment: Perhaps you  are requesting Json, but the server isn't returning it? You include contentType in post but not the get

Comment: Is this is a cross-domain post request?

Comment: @Slowcoder if it were, he wouldn't be getting 500 server error in the error callback

Comment: @theporchrat It is supposed to return JSON.  When I run the curl command it returns JSON.

Comment: @David I know what u mean but I just find it easier to use $.post...each one with his preferences...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I notice is a difference in the data representations.  Look at the data in the original request:

```
-d '{"username":"...","password":"..."}'
```

And the data in the AJAX request:

```
data: {username:"...",password:"..."}
```

The former wraps the keys in strings, whereas the latter doesn't.  The whole thing should be a string too.  Try:

```
data: '{"username":"...","password":"..."}'
```

This would be more consistent with [JSON formatted data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in general, I believe.  Without wrapping the keys in strings, it may be a JavaScript object but it's not JSON data.

Comment: I tried both the quoted form you show, and JSON.stringify.  I still get the same 500 error.

Comment: @user1073959: Is there a way to capture the actual HTTP request being sent by `curl`?  You can capture the HTTP request for the AJAX version in browser debugging tools.  If you can compare the two then perhaps that can help find how they differ.  Could be a header that's different, for example.

Comment: I don't know how to do that for curl.  But I figured out how to look at it in firefox.  One thing I noticed, is that it reportedly was accepting "application/json", but the content was reported as "json".  I changed the contentType to "application/json" and it works!

Comment: I just checked the jQuery docs, and indeed dataType should be listed as "json" and contentType should be listed as "application/json".  Not sure why they are different.

Comment: @user1073959: Excellent, glad you were able to sort it out.  I've never run into that particular issue before, but it's good to know that there's an explicit server-visible difference between the two.

Comment: @user1073959 content type denotes mime type and one of json's mime type is what you used

Answer (score 1):

Update: oops missed a comment saying stringify didn't work. I'll leave this for posterity

Sometimes you need to stringify the data when sending Json, otherwise jquery may serialize the object as a param string rather than as a whole object.  It depends on how your server binds the request query to the object. though. Can you debug the server request or is that out of your hands?

Try doing (provided you are on a semi modern browser) :

```
   data: JSON.stringify({ your: data})
```

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Json response from the url may be the reason, you can comment the stringfy function and alert the response.  You can use try/catch method in response and check the error.

Comment: I removed contentType, and get still get a 500 error. My impression was that contentType described the data being sent (which should be JSON according to the API), and dataType was the expected return data (which is also JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your help.  Each little piece of advice helped lead me to the solution.  I said it in a comment already, but here is the solution:

1. The dataType is correctly listed as "json", but the contentType should be listed as "application/json".
2. The content must be wrapped in JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

Do you post to the same domain as the js was loaded from? If not you need to use jsonp and make sure the server explicitly accepts your request, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Network in Tools (f12)

2) Select "Network"

3) Select error row

4) Open "Body" on rights side

5) In title you can see error description eq.

*`<title>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'BosCatalog.Controllers.ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.<br>Parameter name: parameters</title>`*